# How to get the value of a specific item from an array object as given below

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

```
ActivationToken {#194 ▼


#fillable: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:5 [▶]
  #original: array:5 [▼
    "token" => "h8diZf"
    "user_id" => 26
    "updated_at" => "2017-01-15 17:46:04"
    "created_at" => "2017-01-15 17:46:04"
    "id" => 26
  ]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
}
```

Here, I want to get the value of token, i.e., h8diZf.
This array is stored in $token.
So, can anyone tell me how to get that value?

Edit:

This is the code to used to set the token, Activation is  a model

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    Auth::logout();

    $token = $user->activationToken()->create([
        'token' => str_random(6),
    ]);

    Mail::to($user)->send(new SendActivationToken($token));
    dd($token);
     return redirect('/activate')->with('token', $token)->with('info', ' Please activate your account. We have sent you a code in your email, please fill it in the box below');
}
```

This is the activationToken model :

```
class ActivationToken extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['token'];

public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'token';
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
}
```

Comment: `$token->token`

Comment: @Frondor No, that's not working

Comment: Can you show us the code in the controller or model? BTW, are you from Israel?

Comment: `$token->getToken()` or `$token->toArray()` as access it directly as array. You're looking it wrong anyway, that seems like an eloquent model under some other function, so yes, we need to see all the code.

Comment: @Frondor I have edited the description to give all the necessary code, check to see if you can help me in any way

Comment: @Eitan I have edited to give the code in the description

Comment: Just like frondor said, $token->token should work. But I also see per page attribute, not sure if your trying to return with pagination. Try collect($token)->pluck('token')

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar $token->token is giving TokenMismatchException. Also, I haven't used any pagination

Comment: I think the TokenMismatchException comes from `Auth::logout()`, not from `$token->token`, which is obviously fine.

Comment: Yes. TokenMismatchException and $token->token are no way connected. It might be you submitted your form after a long gap and laravel expired the token.